# Find the number of ways the N balls could be placed in the M boxes

Tags: c++, algorithm

You have `N` different balls numbered from 1 to `N`, and `M` different boxes numbered from 1 to `M`.

**Input:**

First line of input contains the number of test cases `T`. After that, next `T` lines contain the value of `N` and `M`.

**Output:**

For each test case, print the answer. As it can be very large, you should print it modulo `10^9 + 7`.

I tried the below code, but it gives an error:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned short int T;
    unsigned long int N,M;
    cin>>T;
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        cin>>N>>M;
        long int res;
        res=  pow(M,N);
            int c=0;
            c=pow(10,9);
            res=res%(c + 7);
        cout<<res<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: it gives me an error in some tests

Comment: What error do you get in your tests?

Comment: Wrong answer on test 2

Comment: What is "test 2"? This one's not salvageable.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I can't determine where's exactly the error ?
Please, help me!
I do really need fix it

Comment: Fix what? You haven't given us what the error output is, what test 2 is, or see any code for your second test. Least you can do is provide is what you inputted and what you're expecting to receive

Comment: It's a problem in competitive programming, i just wrote the code and i expected that it'll run correctly but i get a wrong answer
And i can't determine the wrong
I want you to check if my code suitable with these requirments.

Comment: Input

2
3 2
1 10

Output

8
10

Comment: So you're failing at stack overflow *as well* as at competitive programming?

Answer (score 0):

You must be facing `integer overflow` problem, that's why you must have been getting wrong answer.

Do the following steps to fix this problem.

- change the `unsigned long` to `long long` or `unsigned long long`. (**Why**? Think).
- Use the logarithmic user-defined function to calculate the value of the `res = pow(M,N)` along with the modulo consideration side-by-side. This will boost up your program.

See my code snippet to check what changes to be made:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#define MOD 1000000007

int main() {
    unsigned short int T;
    unsigned long long N , M , result;
    unsigned long long power(unsigned long long, unsigned long long); /*prototype of power*/

    std::cin>>T;
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        std::cin >> N >> M;
        result = power(M , N);
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

unsigned long long power(unsigned long long M, unsigned long long N) {
    if(N == 0) {
        return 1;   
    }

    unsigned long long result = power(M , N/2);
    result = (result * result) % MOD;

    if(N%2 == 1) {
        result = (result * M) % MOD;   
    }

    return result;
}
```